# How WP-o-Matic works and how to do the same using ASP.Net? Cron job equivalent in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

[WP-o-Matic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-o-matic/) is a wordpress plugin to auto post based on some configured feeds, it read feeds everything time interval i setup, its working on my blog, my blog is on shared windows web hosting, 
i want to know how it auto work like that, and because i am on a shared hosting, so sure i didn't setup any windows services on the server, so its just keep working just after activating, seams strange idea for me.


[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice article on how to create a [Task Scheduler](http://nayyeri.net/blog/how-to-build-a-task-scheduler-system-for-the-asp-net-ndash-part-1/) (similar to Cron) in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid you will have to write a windows service to run the scheduled jobs in .Net environments. In general, shared hosting companies do not provide a provision to configure a windows service on the servers so you might have to look at other alternative for hosting.